adding node exporter info to prometheus query
I am running multiple docker stacks all providing the infrastructure for a product.
Internally those docker stacks are monitored using Prometheus and alert to a teams channel.
I want all docker stacks alerting to the same teams channel but need a way to tell from which server the notification came.
For example with my rule
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up == 0
    for: 0m
    labels:
      severity: critical

I am generating alerts for instances that go down.
But since I have multiple stacks where all the services have the same internal host-names and IPs the alert generated and send to teams is missing the information from which server the alert came.
I was thinking to maybe merge some node-exporter information like node_dmi_info into the alert expr (up ==0), but I was not able to figure that out yet.
And I am also assuming that the alert only has access to the results of its expression so that I can't simply add something like
labels:
      host: "{{ $labels.product_name }}" 

trying to access node-exporter information.

I suspect you'd benefit from relabeling the Internal labels but be careful using e.g. __address__ (host:port) because this could change. Consider incorporating metadata that corresponds to your servers either using a different job name or by identifying some metadata that's surfaced through Node Exporter's labels that you could use.

See the most excellent Relabeler for help with the gnarly task of define relabelings.

I ended up injecting the hostname coming from the hostname command into prometheus and using that for the alerts by using the flag: --enable-feature=expand-external-labels and the following config:
global:
  ...
  external_labels:
        cluster: ${CLUSTER_NAME}

rule_files:
  - rules.yml

alerting:
  alert_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [cluster]
      action: replace
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: "$1"
      target_label: cluster
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 'prometheus-alert:9093'

as explained here: https://www.lisenet.com/2021/use-external-labels-with-prometheus-alerts/
